# Best layout/nested layouts for this structure

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am new to Swing and I am trying to create an interface like:

`+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
|         Information text         |
|                                  |
+--------+----------------+--------+
|        |    JPwdField   |        |
|        +----------------+        |
| Button |    Button 7    | Button |
|   1    +----------------+   3    |
|        |    JTextField  |        |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+
|        |       |        |        |
|        |       |        |        |
| Button | Button| Button | Button |
|   2    |   5   |   6    |   4    |
|        |       |        |        |
+--------+----------------+--------+`

The idea is that all the buttons expand in their "cell", so I have read about nested `GridLayout`, but I am having problems thinking about how to implement it. Any suggestions about how to nest the layouts or about a better way?

Comment: Please add your best effort as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe we can help you fix it.

Comment: It can be achieved with GirdLayout on multiple nested JPanels. Just depends how gnarly you want to get. You could also use GroupLayouts to achieve this, but they're a bit more difficult to grasp if you have no previous layout knowledge.

Comment: You might also try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for "best way to do it" questions. They will also want to see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` will act as an optimal solution, in terms of complexity in the readability of the code. Since this outcome is best suited for `GridBagLayout`, just if one knows how to workaround with the constraints of the same :-)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagLayoutExample {

    private GridBagConstraints gbc;
    private JButton[] buttons;

    public GridBagLayoutExample() {
        buttons = new JButton[7];
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));          
        }
        JLabel informationLabel = new JLabel("Information Text", JLabel.CENTER);
        addComp(contentPane, informationLabel,
                            0, 0, 1.0, 0.20, 4, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[0],
                            0, 1, 0.25, 0.60, 1, 3);
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
        addComp(contentPane, passwordField,
                            1, 1, 0.50, 0.20, 2, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[6],
                            1, 2, 0.50, 0.20, 2, 1);
        JTextField tField = new JTextField(10);
        addComp(contentPane, tField,
                            1, 3, 0.50, 0.20, 2, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[2],
                            3, 1, 0.25, 0.60, 1, 3);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[1],
                            0, 4, 0.25, 0.20, 1, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[4],
                            1, 4, 0.25, 0.20, 1, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[5],
                            2, 4, 0.25, 0.20, 1, 1);
        addComp(contentPane, buttons[3],
                            3, 4, 0.25, 0.20, 1, 1);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComp(JPanel panel, JComponent comp,
                        int x, int y, double wx, double wy,
                                int gw, int gh) {
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        gbc.weightx = wx;
        gbc.weighty = wy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gw;
        gbc.gridheight = gh;

        panel.add(comp, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image: GRIDBAGLAYOUT]

Comment: Thank you very much! Apart from your code I played a little bit with `ipady` in order to make the buttons from the last row as tall as 1 and 3 and also with the weight for when the application is resized. Your code has been very helpful and I have learned quite Swing playing with it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It's really simple to use and very powerful in my opinion.

The code could look like this:

```
public JPanel createPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 4, fill, debug", "align center", "align center"));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Information text"), "spanx 4, align center center");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 1"), "spany 3");
    panel.add(new JTextField("Password"), "spanx 2");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 3"), "spany 3");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 7"), "spanx 2");
    panel.add(new JTextField("JTextField"), "spanx 2");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 2"), "");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 5"), "");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 6"), "");
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 4"), "");

    return panel;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is hard and fast rule to create an user interface. You can achieve it with number of ways using different layouts.

Please have a look at all the available layouts and choose that suits as per your need.

You can use multiple containers with different layouts and finally add them in an other container.

Read [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

---

You can try with [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or use Vertical Layout containing Horizontal Layout.

Comment: Here is the [GridBagLayout Tutorial](http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/) for start-up.